# How to execute below requests once ssh host logged through beanshall pre processor java script in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, performance, testing, jmeter

I have connected ssh host trough beanshall pre processor java script, after that I have to execute couple(around 20 test cases) of http sampler requests in that same host.

Example:
Connected **ssh 10.12.38.231:12 username and password**
Logged above host using javascript Pre processor
Next i want to copule of http sampler in same host.

Am able to see logged into host in Jmeter console output
But those request running in my local machine not in host.

Is there any way to execute this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ivank, You need to use master - node concept (i.e., distributed load)to execute the script in the remote machine.

Comment: Yeah Chandra, we can do that but in my point I have already connected that host from my local Jmeter. Is there any chance execute from local

Comment: If you need to execute the Jmeter script in another machine, that machine need to have jmeter setup in it.

We can do your requirement in Two ways

1) You can use Distributed Load Concept
2) You need to setup Jmeter on another remote machine and also the script you need to execute on it. Then You can execute the script from main machine using commands of Non-GUI. This way you can run the script on remote machine from another machine using command line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to the remote machine over SSH and run the requests **on that remote machine** you have 2 options:

1. Transferring the JMeter test plan from the local machine to the remote one using i.e. [SSH SFTP sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp)
2. Installing JMeter onto that machine and kicking off the test in command-line non-GUI mode using [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) sampler

Both samplers can be installed as a part of `SSH Protocol Support` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

[image]

---

Also forget about Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.